How can I make vue app loaded more than six tabs
I have a strange problem that even I don't know what is the source. I have a vue app, which works without any problem but if I open the in the 7th or more tab the request doesn't get response and it is hanging on pending stage. If I close one of my tabs, the pending request gets response. What can be the source of the problem and how can I fix it.
Any idea would be much appreciated. Here is my package.json.
{
  "name": "App name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "App description",
  "author": "me",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "staging": "git push heroku-staging master",
    "prod": "git push heroku master",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "vue-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.0",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "^3.6.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.8.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.0.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "eslint": "^3.7.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^2.0.5",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^1.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
    "function-bind": "^1.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "opn": "^4.0.2",
    "ora": "^0.3.0",
    "vuejs-paginate": "^2.1.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "<= 12.22.11",
    "npm": "<= 6.14.16"
  }
}

If you need any more details, I can provide.
Thanks

what request are you talking about?  please post enough code and information to make the issue reproducible.  see creating MCVE.  providing a github repo or online sandbox would be ideal.

if you are using Chrome and the previous opened 6 tabs still waiting for response, or still recieving data from the server, the 7th tab won't work.
it is a Chrome TCP concurrent limit

previous tabs fully opened and operational. no problem. @yoduh, it is the first request which tries to load the app, localhost:{portNumber}.
